# more pythonic way to do dictionary calculations

Tags: python, dictionary, math

I am trying to use a dictionary to divide its elements in order to get a value. If that value is in my criteria I wish to stop. I have managed to make it work, but I feel there must be a shorter way. If you have any suggestions or advice I would appreciate it.

```
dict1 = {1:123, 2:220, 3:290, 4:300, 5:329} 
prev = 1 
prev_key = 1 
for key,value in dict1.items():
    z = prev/value
    if z >= 0.95 and z<= 1.05:
        print("key is",prev_key)
        break
    prev = value
    prev_key = key
```

In this scenario the answer is prev_key = 3. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Running your code never enters the if clause.

Comment: Note that depending on the python version the dictionary may not have a unique iteration order.

Comment: @Darina sorry yes I have now updated it to 3:290. my bad

Comment: @tobias_k makes a good point. First step should be converting the dictionary to two lists and possibly sorting.

Comment: I am running on python 3.6 
What do I achieve by converting it into lists?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you get opinions on working code at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think you don't need to use a dictionary. Instead, you can use a list:
`for key, value in enumerate([123, 220...])`

Answer (score 0):

First, like was mentioned in the comments, dictionaries do not have a reliable iteration order in older python versions. I would to the following

```
# convert dictionary to list of key/value tuple pairs
l = [(k, v) for (k, v) in dict1.items())

# iterate over the list of tuples, using zip to get the previous and current value at once
for tup1, tup2 in zip(l, l[1:]):
    z = t1[1] / t2[1]
    if 0.95 <= z <= 1.05:
        print('key is', t1[0])
        break
```

Dictionaries are insertion ordered in Python 3.6, so you should be fine. But if you need to sort the list by key value first (looks like that in your MWE), you can do `l = sorted(l, key = lambda x: x[0])` - this sorts the list by the first value of the tuples. If you are relying on dictionary key order for your code, you should use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Forgot about the `prev` initialization - that can be achieved by prepending `l += [(1,1)]` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a bit shorter (and IMHO more readable) by (a) using comparison chaining (also meaning you don't need `z`), and (b) making multiple assignments of things that belong together on the same line:

```
dict1 = {1:123, 2:220, 3:290, 4:300, 5:329} 
prev = prev_key = 1 
for key,value in dict1.items():
    if 0.95 <= prev/value <= 1.05:
        print("key is", prev_key)
        break
    prev, prev_key = value, key
```

For more aggressive shortening, you could use `next` instead of a loop and break, and use the `zip(*[iter(...)]*2)` recipe to iterate pairs of values; note, however, that this does not mix well with initializing `prev` with `1`; you'd rather have to have a first entry of `1: 1` in the dict itself.

```
print("key is", next(prev_key for (prev_key, prev), (key, value) in zip(*[iter(dict1.items())]*2)
                              if 0.95 <= prev/value <= 1.05))
```

However, in my opinion the first (longer) version is much more readable.

Or unroll the `dict1.values()` into a list together with `(1, 1)` and then `zip` that with itself offset by one. Together with shorter variable names, that's quite readable, too.

```
lst = [(1, 1), *dict1.items()]
print("key is", next(k1 for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(lst, lst[1:])
                        if 0.95 <= v1/v2 <= 1.05))
```

Bother versions with `next` will raise an exception if no such element is found. you can e.g. use `next((...), default=None)` to counter this.